# disable login by editing /etc/password file

Tags: linux, scripting, users, password

I am assigned to generate a script that can disable password login for ssh service. Knowing that I can perform this action by editing /etc/sshd_config file, but my mentor mentioned the file I should look into is /etc/password file. That was the hint for me to perform this task. Here is what I did, I removed the 'x' symbol in the user. I believed the field is reserved for hashing password.

The original

```
 pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

After edited:

```
 pi::1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

The result:
 Without the key I'm stuck with retyping the pass window.

Updated for clarity: The script should be used to reply on public and private key in order to login to the  pi server. To put it another way, I try go for password-less login, making it a feature to harden security.

Comment: A long time ago you could replace bash by nologin???

Comment: I tried and got this message: Last login: This account is currently not available.

Comment: Historically replacing the hash with an invalid one such as '*' disabled password logins. (Changing the login shell didn't prevent using su to access the account from another user account.) I suspect the same functionality remains in the shadow package, but keep in mind that you're disabling all password access not just ssh.

Comment: Just making the second field of `/etc/passwd` empty is a dangerous method that relies on your PAM configuration (or a setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or in some other login method that won't use PAM) disabling network/remote logins for passwordless accounts. After your edit, try logging in on the console as user `pi`: you may find out that you can get in with just pressing enter at the password prompt. It's safer to set the password field to an invalid value like `*`, as suggested by @MatthewGauthier above.

Comment: Emptying the password field is *definitely* the wrong way to do it.  If the field is "x", logins use the `/etc/shadow` file to determine the password.  If the field is "\*" (or anything that isn't an encrypted password), logins via password will never work.  If the field is empty, then unless some other mechanism prevents it, **anyone can log in to the account without providing any password at all**., the exact opposite of what you want to accomplish.  `sudo vipw` and changing the field to "\*" will effectively disable logins via password, regardless of the method used (ssh, rlogin, etc.).

Comment: Changing `/etc/passwd` also affects logins on the console, not just SSH.

Comment: And I think it will prevent them from using `sudo` if it's configured to ask for a password.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to edit the `/etc/passwd` file directly, although you can if you insist.

```
passwd --lock pi    # Lock the "pi" user account
```

You can see further options, including how to unlock a locked account, with `man passwd`. Needless to say, this command *must* be run with root privileges.

---

Now that I see you have edited your question to explain that you want to disable password-based authentication for ssh, this can be enforced with a simple edit to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Remember to restart the service, `systemctl restart sshd`

Answer (score 0):

While @roaima is correct, `passwd` command or the sshd_config are probably what you want, I want point out a few alternatives:

1) Add an exclamation point to the beginning of the password (which is actually what `passwd -l` does, see the man page). Note that the actual password hash is in `/etc/shadow`, not `/etc/passwd`.

2) Disable ("pre-expire") the account with `usermod --expiredate 1` (or any other day in the past, also from the passwd man page)

3) Change the shell to "/usr/sbin/nologin" via either `chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin` or editing `/etc/passwd`. This is used by many debian children to identify a system/service account to stymie injection attacks against specialized accounts (apache, mail, sshd etc.).

Comment: Any of these will prevent the OP from using `ssh` logins at all.

Comment: Only first option works for me.